Could not find androidx:room:2.7.0-alpha01. in Kotlin Multi Platform
I have started a new sample KMP project, I was gonna build a project include room database. Room version 2.7.0-alpha01 is now support KMP, here is the official documentation. I have added all dependencies to my KMP project as explained here. But can't build the project for the ANDROID app, IOS is working fine.
libs.versions.toml
[libraries]
room = { module = "androidx:room", version.ref = "roomVersion" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomVersion" }

[plugins]
room = { id = "androidx.room", version.ref = "roomVersion" }

build.gradle.kts
plugins{
   alias(libs.plugins.room)
}

androidMain.dependencies {
   implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
   implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
   implementation(libs.room)
   implementation(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
}

When I click the run button and if the configuration is composeApp I am getting the error below.


UPDATE [FIXED]
I just followed the sample KMP + Room project (Fruit sample) to implement room dependencies correctly. Thanks @ianhanniballake for your answer.
libs.versions.toml
androidx-room-compiler = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "roomVersion" }
androidx-room-runtime = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "roomVersion" }
androidx-room-paging = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-paging", version.ref = "roomVersion" }

build.gradle.kts (composeApp)
plugins {
    ......
    alias(libs.plugins.room)
}

room {
    schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
}



 sourceSets {
    
    androidMain.dependencies {
        ......
        implementation(libs.androidx.room.paging)
        implementation(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    }
    commonMain.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
        ......
    }
}

android {

    room {
        schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
    }

    ....
}


You're asking for a dependency called androidx.room:2.7.0-alpha01 - that is not a valid artifact. As explained in the Room KMP docs, the artifact you actually want is androidx.room:room-runtime:2.7.0-alpha01 - note the room-runtime in the middle.
This means your libs.versions.toml should instead look like:
room = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "roomVersion" }
androidx-room-compiler = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "roomVersion" }

You'll note the usage of group and name to split up the androidx.room first part from the proper names for each artifact.

Thanks for the answer. I followed your syntax, there was no error when Sync the gradle but I am still not accessing the files where comes from the room library. For example: @Database annotation, the IDE is not recognizing them. I guess I may miss something. Is there a sample KMP project that include room library? thanks in advance.

The Fruitties sample is a complete project that uses Kotlin Multiplatform Room, DataStore, and Ktor.
